# Definition of semi-elasticity

Tags: elasticity, definition, economic-terms

The "$x$-elasticity of $y$" is defined as $\epsilon = \dfrac{\partial y/y}{\partial x/x}$.

The $x$ goes down, and the $y$ goes up.

But we have two definitions of semi-elasticity:

$\epsilon_1 = \dfrac{\partial y/y}{\partial x}$

Which is the percentage change of $y$ in response to a (non percentage) change of x, and:

$\epsilon_2 = \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x/x}$

Which is the (non percentage) change in $y$ in response to a percentage change in $x$.

How do we distinguish between the two?

That is, what are they called?

When we say "the $x$-semi-elasticity of $y$", what do we refer to?

**REFERENCES**

[STATA manual for rmargins](https://www.stata.com/manuals/rmargins.pdf#page=26), page 26.

---

Note: The actual definition is on [page 47](https://www.stata.com/manuals/rmargins.pdf#page=47).